# Navigating back from a screen removes the bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I have a Main page, and the page Contains a bottom navigation bar with five options, among which one is "Tasks". I am calling all the pages on this main page when an option from the tab is clicked. For example, if I have a class called task, when I click on the task tab, I am not navigating TO task; I am calling Task Class in the main page's Body.

This task page has cards that navigate the user to a Chat page, so when I pop back from the chat page, I am popping back to the task page and not the Main page, therefore the bottom navigation bar is not visible. Is there a workaround or method so that the bottom navigation bar is not removed and stays there throughout the app? Also, I am using go_route for routing

Comment: Can you post the code of your Main Page with the bottom navigation bar?